# Symplectic and Euclidean structure invariance

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

Consider a $2n$ real symplectic space - the usual $\mathbb R^{2n}$.

Suppose that the same space could be endowed too with an Euclidean structure, by which the vectors of the symplectic basis are orthogonal.

On p. 28 in [*Symplectic Geometry* by A. T. Fomenko](https://books.google.it/books?id=SrXrqo5qaWQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=it&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=destroyed&f=false) it is said that

> Generally speaking, the connection between the Euclidean and the
>   symplectic structures [...] is destroyed by any linear non-singular
>   transformation of $\mathbb R^{2n}$.

I think that such "connection" is indeed preserved by transformations of the unitary group...am I wrong?

Comment: Are you assuming that the metric $g$ and the symplectic structure $\Omega$ are compatible, i.e. is $J:=g^{-1}\Omega$ an almost complex structure $J^2=-\mathbb{1}$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment but...What do you mean? I thought the compatibility was assured by the fact the symplectic basis is also orthonormal